# i converted eclipse Application into net beans it showing error unmappable character for encoding UTF-8

Tags: java, swing

i converted Eclipse application into net beans 7.2  version that showing some error like this
unmappable character for encoding UTF-8

please help me how to resolve this problem

Comment: into project properties is option for to change Charset

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check the Project properties. In the `Sources` category there is `Encoding`, set it to `UTF-8`.